# should we make a wpf application run from commandline (any path, not just the installed path)?

Tags: .net, wpf, command-line

We have a WPF application which will be generally installed onto a folder, with all the dependent resources (like images, etc.).

Should we provide the user with the ability to run the app from command line (from any path) not just the installation path?

If so how can we do that, i.e. how can we make the resources available anywhere? Right now it’s not working in paths other than the installation folder, as the dependent resources are not available.

[Edit]
i am accessing the resources like this
string resPath = @"\Content\Images\image1.png";

Comment: Are you talking about making the application run even if the user copies the executable into an alternate directory *without* the associated resources that it depends on? No, of course not. That's called "breaking it".

Comment: @Nar is this pattern based on some other application you're familiar with?  What are you trying to accomplish by giving this ability to the user?

Comment: Not copying the executable, but just executing the exe with full path

Comment: Uh, if you execute the executable with the full path, then everything should work as expected. How in the world does it *not* for your application?

Comment: One of my question is , is it correct to provide this ability to user.

Comment: the reason its not working is b'z the associated resources are not available from the path where it is executed.

Comment: That's wrong. By default, the application searches in *its* directory for its associated resources, not in the default path. If you're doing something else, then your code is wrong. Post the code that accesses those resources so we can tell you how to fix it. This is functionality that you should get entirely for free.

Comment: the code is something like this string resPath = @"\Content\Images\

Answer (score 1):

Write an application that will run your wpf application in the correct working directory using ProcessStartInfo. You will need to add this application to the user's Path so the user can run the application from the command prompt.

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\code\wpf.exe", "");
processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\code";
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Comment: If you only add wpf.exe to the path and run it from the command prompt, then wpf.exe will run in whatever directory you are currently in. The problem is the external dependencies that are in C:\Code will not be found because that is not the working directory.

Comment: Right, that's why you don't add `wpf.exe` to the path. Don't solve a local problem with a global solution. I don't want your installer cluttering up my `PATH`.

Comment: i dont think i want to create a new application to solve this.